# Isekai about a small girl with glasses who was transported to another world and has a skill named "print"

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

About one year ago I saw this manga about a girl who has a skill named "print" and can make grimoires, and basically made a comiket but only magical books and sometimes books about other gods. She is petite with black hair and glasses and has pulled an Excalibur-like sword that she used for cutting the sides of books. She has a sidekick, not really a sidekick but a co-worker, that I think is a bear (I don't know for sure if it was a bear) and she has another coworker that is a girl and who cuts the edges of books with her axe or sword. She does an event where many people go to a reverse pyramid place that sells many books about magic. She is trying to find her way back to her world.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please review the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/101407) for asking anime-ID questions and [edit] any extra details you remember into your question.  (You'll also get a better response if you fix your question to have sentences and paragraphs.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely *[A Witch's Printing Office](https://mangakakalot.com/manga/a_witchs_printing_office)*.

[image: Front cover of *A Witch's Printing Office*]

> Mika Kamiya is a young woman who is a "magic printer" - that is, she helps to create grimoirs and other mystic books which witches and wizards can use. However, she cannot use any magic herself. Desperate to find a spell which can send her back to her home world, Mika decides to create a COMpetely magIcal marKET, where magicians can trade and show off their creations.

Found with a search for `isekai print skill grimoires`